# Is Accord.NET framework and .NET Core 2 Compatible?

Tags: c#, .net-core, accord.net

I have been looking to see if Accord .NET framework is capable of running on NET Core 2.2 but I am not finding any specific release info when gargling - I do not get any hits for specific relevant information.

Comment: Just test it. Create a dummy .net core console app and try to install and use this package?

Comment: @vasily.sib
I have so many projects going on right now and this will be on a raspberry pi (which is on order) - I would like to be able to make an informed choice and not put a lot of time into testing nuances for something that may not work - would rather put effort into the desired end result.